# " Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable' " error when refering to drawables

Tags: java, android, layout, drawable, overlapping

***NOW IM USING HORIZONTAL SLIDER WITH RELATIVE LAYOUT.
Its doing what i want the program to do, and in a simpler way.
but this error ( below ) is still there.***

I'm new and trying to make an app where basically there are multiple buttons (15) on the mainscreen and one of them shows text when clicked ( its working fine ) all other activities are empty but the layout opens when button is pressed, except the family button which is not empty
the **family button (id: butfamily) when pressed, makes the app stop working.**

**I want the family button to show multiple pictures from the drawable (2 for now), which can be slided horizontaly.**

I believe the activity is called correctly and the issue is with the family.class or activity_family.xml

Here is the Android Device -> Errors
(i dont know how this helps but many people post it here so..)

```java
04-12 11:11:55.525 2537-2537/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
```

Here is the family.java class

```java
packagenamehere;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class family extends PagerAdapter {
    private int [] imageResources ={R.drawable.capture3,R.drawable.capture4};
    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public family(Context c) {
        ctx=c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return imageResources.length;
    }



    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_family,container,false);
        ImageView imageView=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swip_image_view);
        TextView textView=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageCount);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageResources[position]);
        textView.setText("Image No# "+position);
        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

        return  (view==object);
    }
}
```

The activity is shown in manifest

Need Help, Thanks a Bunch :)

Comment: Please read the [help] and learn how to create a [mcve] and then come back and edit your question.

Comment: I removed 99% of the main activity and removed the android manifest.

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to be copied from somewhere else.

**Here is what you can try**

1. Verify resource files called capture3, capture4 are there under the drawable directiory
2. remove and re-add them
3. Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: Yes the Sliding class is copied from a youtube tutorial. the options you gave, have been tried. The tutorial code works fine when i have it on main page, i switched the layout and the activity and made necessary changes. but the app closes when i press the button.

Comment: Did you verify resource files called capture3, capture4 are there under the drawable directiory?

Comment: I had a file crunch error, which i resolved by editing the files properly and changing the extension to png correctly. and yes the files are present.

Comment: I'm now using the horizontal slider with relative layout child its doing the job for me, and i dont have to stress these complicated codes, maybe i should go with my own pace :)